# ScrollView's scrollbar isn't showing or when it doesn't go all the way

Tags: java, android, layout, view, scroll

recently when developing a android app I've had to use a scroll view for the settings of the app. The problem with my scroll view is that its not scrolling when i set the layout params to match parent but when i set it to '1000' for example, the scroll bar does appear but only scrolls half the way of the child. Aswell when i try to raise the value of '1000' the scroll view's scroll bar disappears and doesnt scroll anymore. I've put the scroll view inside or a linear layout since for what i've googled was meant to fix it. i put a linear layout to be the child of the scroll view and a class is called to add children to the linear layout of the scroll view. a linear layout (called set1, I'm bad at naming values) is a parent of a scroll view (called "scrollView") and that scroll view is a parent of a linear layout (called set, set for settings). inside of the class that adds children to the linear layout of the scroll view holds: text view, edit texts and views which each have their own translation y. how can i get the scroll view to scroll and show all the contents of its children?

i dont think you would need the contents of the class which adds children to the linear layout (child of scroll view)

declaration:

```
settings sett = new settings();
// some of the given values given to the class dont need to be mentioned but they are buttons and image views 
//passes 'set' which is the child of the scroll view
            sett.setup(con, set , activity, lo, image, upload, images);
            set.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
         
            set.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            scrollView.addView(set);
set1.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ((height -  (int) (height/7.5)) - (int) (height -(height/1.1)) )));
            scrollView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            scrollView.setSmoothScrollingEnabled(true);
set1.setTranslationY((int) (height/7.5));
scrollView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
            scrollView.setFillViewport(true);
            scrollView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
            scrollView.setScrollContainer(true);




            scrollView.setTranslationZ(4);
            scrollView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);

            scrollView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
            scrollView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
            scrollView.setFillViewport(true);
            scrollView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
         scrollView.requestLayout();
         scrollView.invalidate();
set.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
            set1.addView(scrollView);
            layout.addView(set1);
// prints the height of scroll view 
            Log.d("PrintResult", String.valueOf(((height -  (int) (height/7.5)) - (int) (height -(height/1.1)) )) + " " + set.getHeight());
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem that I faced seemed like the set translation and didn't really effect how far the scroll view when down. This wasn't on any website that I saw, must've been the environment of views I used. But for future reference, for people coming later and encountering the same problem. How I fixed it was adding a text view at the bottom of the scroll view. which had a high text size that for some reason effected the scroll view more than the set translation.